# Android SDK Wall Post is not showing on friends news feed

Tags: facebook-wall, facebook-android-sdk

I wrote a simple Android application using Facebook Android SDK that only to post one brief message on wall. The "message" does not contain any media link. After ran the application, the text message was shown on my own facebook page. But it does not show on the new feeds page (i.e. most recent feed update page, or the home page of facebook).

Since the code is very simple, I couldn't find any problem in it. I really appreciate if anyone can provide some suggestion or advise on it.

Here is the code:

```
mFacebook.authorize(
    FacebookPostActivity.this,
    new String[] { "publish_stream", "read_stream" },
    new SimpleDialogListener() );
...
mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner( mFacebook );
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "Some Message" );
mAsyncRunner.request( 
    "me/feed", 
    params, 
    "POST", 
    new SimpleRequestListener(), 
    null );
```

Comment: I'm joining this question. Did you succeed in that?